# Where are Glowing Mushrooms located?

Tags: terraria

I thought they were in the Underground Jungle but I haven't seen any in my limited searching there. Should I be looking elsewhere?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On the unofficial [Terraria wikia](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Glowing_Mushroom) it is written that Glowing Mushrooms are found anywhere inside the Stone Layer.

The [official wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Glowing_Mushroom) just states that Glowing Mushrooms can be found in deeper parts of the Underground.

As of the most recent update, the area with glowing mushrooms is easier to recognize, because it is now its own mini-biome, with its own background and background music.  It is still located only in the Stone Layer, in the deeper parts of the underground.

The blue grass Glowing Mushrooms grows on, can be harvested and planted elsewhere, to make it easier to get more mushrooms. The grass can only be planted on Mud.

Comment: Ohhh NOT in the jungle but stone area near blue grass.  I haven't seen the blue grass which is why I haven't seen glowing 'shrooms.

Comment: Indeed. I have never found blue grass in a jungle.

Comment: Recommended mining pattern for finding them or just start digging down and across?

Comment: As they can appear anywhere in the stone layer, I don't think there is a certain method of finding them, other than pure luck :]

Comment: You can however, when you find one, mine the blue grass, and place it in a favorable place. Like close to home. New Glowing Mushrooms will grow there (only on mud).

Comment: Oddly I am almost ready to go with the farm, just need the seeds :)  Thanks!

Comment: As an FYI, the wiki you linked to is not the [Official Terraria Wiki](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Terraria_Wiki)

Comment: Oh! - I'll be darned. I always assumed it was the original, I guess the official wiki should be used instead. Thank you, Raven.

Comment: But there is more information on the wikia page, should I not use the source with the most information?

Comment: @Simon there's not *more* information, it simply consolidates the Glowing Mushroom and Glowing Mushroom Farm pages.

Comment: The deeper "parts of the underground" mentioned are the ones with darker background. Also, their seeds can only be planted under the ground level, either use the height meter or plant them at the level rocks start appearing in the background and you'll be safe.

Comment: @Simon Wikia -is- the original, but it was based on pre-release data initially and took a while to come around. Red/Blue dumped all the game assets to the TerrariaOnline guys (ie: Curse) and then that wiki took off from there. Id say its a much better source of information, and easier to navigate, than the wikia one.

Comment: Also I've seen some edits in the wikia that are just there for no reason like subbing a word for 'Dick'.

Comment: @Robb — That's the bummer of a wiki, and why it's important to have active contributors.  And also, therefore, why we should be encouraging everybody to use the same one. ;-)

Comment: I beleive this answer needs to be updated. Recent changes I believe have made it so that Glowing Mushroom Grass can only grow in Stone layer, meaning a certain depth is required before you can start planting.

Answer (score 3):

They're generally in caverns with "mushroom trees". I don't think they're terribly common though.

Since they're caverns, digging horizontally might be a better bet, once you've got to an appropriate depth where you might be able to find some.

Comment: Digging down to the Underground level (distinct music and background change) and searching horizontally is definitely a good strategy.  Mushroom biomes are large enough that just a little bit of zig-zagging up and down at that level while travelling through caves horizontally will usually net you a biome.